# l1.slice() parameter is not a function

Tags: javascript, slice

I'm encountering an odd problem when going through leetcode (Merge Two Sorted Lists
). When I run the code below on the leetcode, I got the error below.

> Blockquote
> TypeError: l1.slice is not a function

```js
function mergeSortedArray(l1, l2) {
  console.log(l2.slice(indexA));
  var sorted = [],
    indexA = 0,
    indexB = 0;
  while (indexA < l1.length && indexB < l2.length) {
    if (sortFn(l1[indexA], l2[indexB]) > 0) {
      sorted.push(l2[indexB++]);
    } else {
      sorted.push(l1[indexA++]);
    }
  }
  if (indexB < l2.length) {
    sorted = sorted.concat(l2.slice(indexB));
  } else {
    sorted = sorted.concat(l1.slice(indexA));
  }
  return sorted;
}

function sortFn(l1, l2) {
  return l1 - l2;
}
console.log(mergeSortedArray([1, 2, 3, 5, 9], [4, 6, 7, 8]));
```

However the code is working correctly when I tried the same code on the Chrome, and I got the output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

I consider that the error: 'something is not a function' occurs when there was an attempt to call a value from a function, but the value is not actually a function.
'Slice' is used with an array and l1 is an array in this case.
I don't understand why the output is different between leetcode and Chrome.

Comment: I don't see an `l1` variable in the code you posted?

Comment: I found [this similar error](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/212755/getting-reverse-is-not-a-function) on another problem, so it may be a bug in Leetcode.

Comment: @JoshG the variable `l1` is a parameter of the `mergeSortedArray` function

Comment: Hi JoshG, Thank you for the comment. I corrected the mistakes on the code I posted. Yui

Comment: How exactly are you running the code? When I copy and paste the codeblock into https://leetcode.com/playground/new/empty (with the language set to JavaScript) it seems to work fine.